# A question about the conditional PDF?

Tags: probability

Here is the question:

**In this problem:**

**(i) X is a (continuous) uniform random variable on [0, 4].**

**(ii) Y is an exponential random variable, independent from X, with parameter λ = 2.**

**Find the PDF of Z=X+Y given that Y=3.**

I get the $f_Z(z)$ here:

$ f_Z(z)  = \int_{max(0,z-4)}^{z} \frac{1}{4}2e^{-2t}\,dt $ = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4}(1-e^{-2z}),    & \text{if $0\ll z \ll 4 $,} \\
\frac{1}{4}(e^{8}-1)e^{-2z} , & \text{if $ z > 4 $,}\\
0,         & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

(Sorry for my bad use of Tex..)

And I think that Z = X + Y,  when $Y = 3 $, then $ Z = X + 3$, so I change the z to $x+3$ in the above formula...And I get a wrong answer..

The right solution: ***Given that $Y = 3, Z = X + 3 $and the conditional PDF of Z is a shifted version of the PDF of X.***

I know what the answer means.. But where is the mistake in my solution? Please help! Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you calculated the pdf of $Z$, $f_Z(z)$ by convolution. Then you say you evaluate $f_Z(x+3)$ - this function, if, as a function of $x$, is the pdf of $Z - 3$: i.e. $f_{Z - 3}(x) = f_Z(x + 3)$. Or, in other words, you seems to find $X + Y - 3$ instead.

Comment: You say  $f_{Z-3}(x)$ , not $f_X(z-3)$ ? Why do I find $X + Y -3$ instead? It seems that $Y$ is not included..

Comment: Hello?Are you still here?

Comment: You say you know what the answer means.. so do you believe or even understand that the right solution you get? Initially you think that your approach should also be able to give a correct solution, but it does not match with the correct answer you have. And you asked what is the mistake? The mistake is that you are not calculating the required function, you are calculating other stuffs that are very far away from the answer. Therefore in the previous comment I try to give an interpretation of the function you find (at least not garbage in garbage out).

Comment: Also I suggest you to review on those fundamental concepts about transformation of random variable. It looks weird that you can apply the convolution formula to obtain the pdf of $Z = X + Y$, but have serious conceptual error on the other related area.

Comment: Yep, I understand the correct answer, but I do not grasp my mistake.. Also, I could not understand your answer.. Do you mean Laplace Transform in probability ? I do not learn it before..

Comment: Sorry for my stupid head... I just could not understand..

Comment: I do not think I can express the answer much clearer, but I can try to rephrase it step by step: 1) You have calculated $f_Z(z)$; 2) You try to evaluate $f_Z(x+3)$ (this is correspond to your statement "I change the $z$ to $x+3$ in the above formula"); 3) You are curious whether this function, $g(x) = f_Z(x+3)$ is the function $f_{Z|Y=3}$ you want; the answer is obviously no as you have compared them. 4) For your exercise: given a pdf $f_W(w)$, find the pdf of $W - 3$ in terms of $f_W$. You should be able to understand the answer after finish this.

Comment: I calculated today, and find that $f_{Z|Y-3}$ is *condtional* , and $f_{Z}$ is *total*, so I know where I am wrong. Thank you very much!